# Iterate over a dictionary in Python

Tags: python

How can I iterate over my dictionary? I need to print details of every items.

```
my_dict = {
   'item':[
      {
         'date':'1990',
         'name':'test',
         'image':'/media/item/img.jpg',
         'desc':'Sample desc'
      },
      {
         'date':'1991',
         'name':'test1',
         'image':'/media/item/img1.jpg',
         'desc':'Sample desc1'
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary has the ability to iterate over itself to print each item. To simply print the details of each item as you have asked, simply use the print command:

```
>>> ourNewDict = {'name': 'Kyle', 'rank': 'n00b', 'hobby': 'computing'}
>>> print ourNewDict

Output: {'hobby': 'computing', 'name': 'Kyle', 'rank': 'n00b'}
```

Or, to print keys and values independently:

```
>>> print ourNewDict.keys()
Output: ['hobby', 'name', 'rank']
>>> print ourNewDict.values()
Output: ['computing', 'Kyle', 'n00b']
```

If I read into your question more, and guess that you'd like to iterate through each object to do more than simply print, then the items() command is what you need.

```
>>> for key, value in ourNewDict.items():
...     print key
... 
hobby
name
rank
>>> for key, value in ourNewDict.items():
...     print value
... 
computing
Kyle
n00b
>>>
```

And to be very generic:

```
>>>for someVariableNameHere in someDictionaryNameHere.items():
...     doStuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You iterate through a dictionary just like an array, but instead of giving you the values in the dictionary it gives you the keys.

```
> my_dict = {"a" : 4, "b" : 7, "c" : 8}
> for i in my_dict:
...  print i

a
b
c
```

You can then access the data in the dictionary like you normally would. (This is achieved with square brackets, so `my_dict["a"]` would give 4.)